# Magento, displaying empty page - only link showing

Tags: php, magento

I'm using magento and have tried refreshing indexes, clearing cache etc.

However, something weird is happening. Magento is displaying blank pages for Categories. There is a link on the page, because I can click on it, but it is not visible. There is also an H1 tag. However there is no product image, no text for the product link etc.

Its almost like magento cant find the CSS for the center of the page. Also I notice there is a long number before the CSS file e.g. /media/css/39328749837294823.css

Im wondering if anyone knows why this might be?

Cheers

K

Comment: Its sounds like maybe there is a PHP error somewhere in one of your templates or a helper one of those templates is using. Turn on `display_errors` and set error reporting to `E_ALL`. Also take a look in your `MAGENTO_INSTALL/var/log/system.log` and see if there is any info there. As far as the CSS file... do you have any plugins that are compiling CSS?

Comment: Yep, Ive got E_All added to the top of my index.php file, no errors are output. I dont seem to get anything in my /var/log/system.log maybe this is because it's unwritable?

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the system.log looking into these errors now :)

Comment: Your long number before the CSS file is because you have CSS merging turned on in System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer.